# Which Javascript library works best with Tornado for a realtime app?

Tags: javascript, python, tornado

I am looking for cross browser support and better integration on the server-side, kind of like how socket.io is so easy to set up with node.js. I am currently using socket.io with tornadio. Any other suggestions I should look into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check sockjs-tornado: https://github.com/MrJoes/sockjs-tornado

I found SockJS client to be more stable than socket.io one.